# O(1) method of getting K using V with a java hashmap?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, hashmap

In Java 8 is there an O(1) method of getting the K by using V for a hashmap? Would I have to use two hashmaps(KV and VK) and if so would that defeat the purpose of having O(1)?

For context, I am trying to find the most efficient way of getting (String userName, Integer userIdentifier) using either value or key.

Comment: There is no method for `O(1)` lookup via value. You could use another `HashMap` like what you mentioned, provided the values are unique.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, the values are unique. No user can have the same userIdentifier and vice versa.

Comment: There is a `BiMap` in Guava, both sides can be used as key as you require, KV & VK

Comment: The key by definition is the data you use to lookup, and the value is the data looked up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general note - there's a hidden assumption here that the values are also unique. Otherwise, you won't be able to retrieve a single key by a value, but a list of keys, although even if you take that into consideration it won't change the answer much. Additionally, with your usecase of userName and userId, this may be a moot point altogether.

As you alluded, a simple `HashMap` won't be enough - that would mean you'd need to iterate over the entries to find an entry with a specific key, which would be an O(n) operation.

Using two `HashMap`s (name to id and id to name) is a good approach. While this would mean you'd have to perform two operations instead of one each time you add/remove/modify a user, it won't affect the order of magnitude (since you're still performing a constant number of constant-time operations), and you'll retain the O(1) insertion time.
This is in fact a pretty common approach, and if you can introduce third-party libraries to your project, there are pretty solid implementations of this concept out there, like Apache Commons Collections' [DualHashBidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/bidimap/DualHashBidiMap.html).

Answer (score 4):

Maps are meant for searching by key, so you won't get O(1) lookup by value, unless you use a second map.

What serves your use case is a `BiMap` avaliable from [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
BiMap<String, Integer> nameidmap = HashBiMap.create();
Integer id = nameidmap.get("name");
String name = nameidmap.inverse().get(12345);
```

Internally Guava also maintains two hash tables, but it does the heavy lifting of keeping the two maps in sync. You can find full Javadoc for Bimap [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only single hashmap,  you can do

> map.put(key, value) and then map.put(value, key)

Assuming values are unique and also not equal to any key